# How to query children of Lit-element shadow root using tag name

Tags: javascript, lit-element

Is there is a way to get a child lit-element (by its name) in the host?
        I only know how to access them using id and `this.shadowRoot.getElementById()`

```
import { LitElement, html } from 'lit-element';
import './child-element.js';

class ParentElement extends LitElement {
  render() {
    return html`<child-element someattribute="somevalue"></child-element>`;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out it was simply calling `shadowRoot.querySelector("element-name")`:

```
...
class ParentElement extends LitElement {
  render() {
    return html`<child-element someattribute="somevalue"></child-element>`;
  }
  aMethod() {
    let childElement = this.shadowRoot.querySelector("child-element");
  }
}
...
```